# how to find an item in the scene

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene

How I can find a particular item in the scene and remove it .
I have declared a graphicsitem and added it to the scene. Now in certain case I have to remove the item from the scene but before removing the item from the scene I want to know the item is added to scene or not. If I try to remove the item which is not added to the scene, I get the below error:

```
"QGraphicsScene::removeItem: item 0x121c520's scene (0x0) is different from this scene (0x1143850)"
```

the item is not selected so I can not use the scene()->selectedItem() list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the pointer returned from calling [QGraphicsItem::scene()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#scene). It will either return the scene, or NULL if it is not present in a scene.

```
// assuming item is a class derived from QGraphicsItem
if(item->scene() != nullptr) // nullptr from C++ 11, else use NULL
{
    // item is in a scene
}
```

Comment: Thanks Merlin . i tested it . it is working fine .. earlier i was trying to check the scene::itemAt(pos) and checking its graphics type .now it is easy and clean . thanks once again ..

Comment: i will accept the answer after 5 min . as i cant accept now .

Comment: No problem, itemAt(pos) won't work for you because if the item is in the scene, then you assume that pos is where your item resides. If it is not at that location, it will return false, even though it can be in the scene.

Comment: you are right . now i got a better solution from you .